# How to send array from android to dotnet webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have multiple values which I want to send from android to DotNet Webservice.

All values are store in array.

**Dotnet method code:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void setApprovedEmp(string[] arrCheckedEmpIds)
{
     // Use array here.
}
```

**Android code:**

```
String[] arrIds = { "1009", "1001", "1012" }; // Array data is dynamic, not fix size
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrCheckedEmpIds", arrIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arrIds = { "1009", "1001", "1012" };
for(int i = 0 ; i <arrIds.length ; i++){
  parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrCheckedEmpIds", arrIds[i]));
}
```

Comment: It is not working.. when I'm trying to get array in Dotnet, it will be display one element in array, and that first element have full string of parameter which I send from android.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize you parameters object into JSON, so you would get something like this:

```
{
    "arrCheckedEmpIds":["1009", "1001", "1012"]
}
```

And send it as request payload into your WebMethod via POST request, with content-type and accept headers set to "application/json".

Comment: How can I serialize parameter object into JSON?

Comment: I dont know how to do it in Java/Android, but I'm sure you will find tons of material on the net how to do it manually or with library.